# Stop lines from shifting when moved up and down (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: visual-studio-code, shortcut

I have this problem when I shift lines up and down using the 'alt' key in Visual Studio Code. Sometimes, when the line is moved up or down it will shift left. It will shift either all the way to the left or the beginning of the 'if' or 'do' loop the line is in. It will sometimes also shift the line that it is permuted with as well. Does anyone else have this problem and know how to stop it?

Answer (score 2):

By turning off the auto-indent in the setting will fix this. I didn't think that would be it because it was removing indentation, but that fixed my problem.

Comment: `"editor.autoIndent": "none",`